# Ordenar un array de objetos con el método de selección

Tags: java

Tengo que ordenar alfabéticamente este arreglo:

```java
arregloEstudiante[0] = new Estudiante("C54411", "Maria", "Mora Mora", 700);
arregloEstudiante[1] = new Estudiante("B92542", "Jose", "Solano Solano", 444);
arregloEstudiante[2] = new Estudiante("C42214", "Alonso", "Solano Mora", 800);
arregloEstudiante[3] = new Estudiante("A95720", "Miguel", "Mora Solano", 550);
arregloEstudiante[4] = new Estudiante("B32567", "Andrea", "Jimenez Ureña", 625);
arregloEstudiante[5] = new Estudiante("C34767", "Fabian", "Sanchez Alvarado", 740);
arregloEstudiante[6] = new Estudiante("C72588", "Martin", "Moya Ureña", 592);
arregloEstudiante[7] = new Estudiante("B42667", "Fabiana", "Sanchez Alvarado", 689);
arregloEstudiante[8] = new Estudiante("A22523", "Mariano", "Mora Mora", 750);
arregloEstudiante[9] = new Estudiante("B4562", "Alonso", "Solano Morales", 497);
```

Hay que ordenar alfabéticamente usando solo el primer atributo el cuál obtengo en la variable mínimo y máximo.
PD: Hay que resolverlo usando el método de ordenación de Selección.

El código de ordenamiento es:

```java
Estudiante[] aux = new Estudiante[1];
int contador = 0;
int contador2 = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < arregloEstudiante.length - 1; i++) {
    String minimo = arregloEstudiante[contador].getCarnet();
    int menor = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arregloEstudiante.length; j++) {
        String maximo = arregloEstudiante[contador2].getCarnet();
        if (minimo.compareTo(maximo) < 0) {
            menor = j;
        } // If
        if (menor == j) {
            aux[0] = arregloEstudiante[i];
            arregloEstudiante[i] = arregloEstudiante[menor];
            arregloEstudiante[menor] = aux[0];
        } // If
    } // For
    contador++;
    contador2++;
} // For Grande

return arregloEstudiante;
```

Esta es mi clase estudiante, estoy usando al versión 1.8 de JAVA para compilar.

```java
public class Estudiante {

    private String carnet;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private int notaAdmision;

    public Estudiante() {

    }// Constructor default

    public Estudiante(String carnet, String nombre, String apellidos, int notaAdmision) {
        this.carnet = carnet;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.notaAdmision = notaAdmision;
    }// Constructor sobrecargado

    public String getCarnet() {
        return this.carnet;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return this.apellidos;
    }
```

En la clase definí cada uno de los atributos, hice los constructores y si no me equivoco está todo correcto, porque invoqué los atributos y los asigné en el `main` de manera correcta y no presentó error.

Comment: C54411
B92542
A95720
A22523
B4562
B32567
B42667
C72588
C42214

este es el resultado más cercano que obtuve.

Comment: agrega la versión de java que estas usando, también agrega la clase **Estudiante** por favor. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El algoritmo de selección se basa en:

- Buscar el mínimo elemento entre una posición `i` y el final de la lista (en este caso sería `arregloEstudiante.length`).
- Intercambiar el mínimo con el elemento de la posición `i`

En pseudocódigo quedaría:

```java
para i=0 hasta n-1
    para j=i+1 hasta n
        si lista[j] < lista[i] entonces
            intercambiar(lista[i], lista[j])
        fin si
    fin para
fin para
```

En código Java quedaría:

```java
Estudiante aux;
for (int i = 0; i < arregloEstudiante.length - 1; i++) 
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arregloEstudiante.length; j++) 
    {
        String minimo = arregloEstudiante[j].getCarnet();
        if (minimo.compareTo(arregloEstudiante[i].getCarnet()) < 0) 
        {
            aux = arregloEstudiante[i];
            arregloEstudiante[i] = arregloEstudiante[j];
            arregloEstudiante[j] = aux;
        } 
    } 
}
```

**Observaciones:**

**1.-** La variable `contador2` está afuera del bucle anidado, por lo tanto, siempre estarás obteniendo el mismo valor en cada iteración (del bucle *anidado*).

Así que el problema principal radica en esta línea:

```java
String maximo = arregloEstudiante[contador2].getCarnet();
```

**Nota:** Esas dos variables son innecesarias, no la necesitas, así que la puedas eliminar.

**2.-** La variable `menor` no la necesitas y tampoco hace falta hacer esta asignación en el `if`:

```java
if (minimo.compareTo(maximo) < 0) {
    menor = j;
} // If
```

Puedes agregar directamente el código de intercambio en el `if` y así se hace el código más simple.

**3.-** No hace falta crear un array de objetos:

```java
Estudiante[] aux = new Estudiante[1];
```

Al final de cuenta solo estarás usando un objeto, así que solo debes declarar una variable donde puedas almacenar la referencia del objeto:

```java
Estudiante aux;
```

**Fuente:**

[Ordenamiento por selección](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_por_selecci%C3%B3n).

Comment: DIOS, muchisimas gracias amigo, gracias por hacerme notar esos gastos de memoria.

pero hay un problema

Lista de estudiantes ordenados
A22523
A95720
B32567
B42667
B4562
B92542
C34767
C42214
C54411
C72588

Comment: @carloszamora ¿Cuál es el problema? Lo está ordenando alfabéticamente, solo que hay algunos valores que su primera letra coinciden, entonces, `compareTo`, tomará la siguiente letra para comparar..

Comment: que A2 no es menor que A9?

Comment: en serio te agradezco por esto, wow, eres muy bueno en este tema. Espero poder llegar a ese nivel. gracias de verdad

Comment: @carloszamora Claro, `A2` es menor que `A9`. Una forma de agradecer es [aceptando la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) que resolvió tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Desde Java 8 en adelante podés hacer:

```javascript
Estudiante[] estudiantesOrdenado = Arrays.stream(arregloEstudiante)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Estudiante::getCarnet))
                .toArray(SmsRaw[]::new);
```

Lo que haces en esa línea es asignar a la variable **estudiantesOrdenado** el resultado de: Convertir el array **arregloEstudiante** a `stream`, para poder recorrerlo. Luego con `sorted` le pasamos una funcion con la que esperamos ordenar el stream generado, en este caso solo comparamos alfabeticamente con la funcion `comparing` de **Comparator** a través del valor optenido del metodo `getCarnet()`. Si se quisiera ordenar de manera descendente se puede utilizar otra funcion de comparacion como `Comparator.reverseOrder()`. Por ultimo, como el resultado de estas operaciones es un stream lo convertimos a un nuevo **Array** para poder asignarlo a la variable **estudiantesOrdenado**

Si lo que buscas es iterar, hay varios algoritmos de ordenamiento ya estudiados, [en este link](http://enrrike87.blogspot.com/2011/06/metodos-de-ordenamiento-java_21.html) se resumen algunos.

Tambien podes hacer uso del metodo `sort` que ofrece **Arrays** de la siguiente manera `Arrays.sort(arregloEsutiantes)`. La explicación la podrás ver [aqui](https://geekytheory.com/tip-java-como-ordenar-un-array-de-objetos-por-sus-atributos).

Comment: Agrega una descripción de lo que haces, no solo postes la respuesta. Con eso no ayudas mucho a la comunidad.

Comment: Postie todo el código, no solo la respuesta, la cosa es que necesito resolverlo usando el método de ordenamiento por selección, no puedo usar librerías que me hagan el proceso, gracias.

Comment: @carloszamora no es ninguna librería, son todas funciones y metodos nativos de Java a partir de la version 8

Comment: Java a partir de la version 8 (marzo 2014)  introdujo nuevos cambios y formas alternativas para hacer cosas, entre ellas: lambda functions, streams, optional .... Hizo un cambio muy grande comenzando una transición o acercamiento al paradigma funcional

Comment: Tengo que usar este método de ordenación.

para i=1 hasta n-1;

   minimo = i;
   para j=i+1 hasta n
       si lista[j] < lista[minimo] entonces
           minimo = j 
       fin si
   fin para
   intercambiar(lista[i], lista[minimo])
fin para

Comment: me disculpan si desconozco algún concepto, estoy comenzando en este mundo y soy un poco noob.

Comment: Me sirvió lo que pasa es que a la hora de implementar el ejemplo de metodo de selección a este tipo de arreglo donde uso uno clase, no me da el resultado. si tu pudieras ayudarme con eso, te agradecería.

Comment: También tu  metodo de selección lo que hace es ordenar de menor a mayor no de mayor a menor, y al final me queda un dato al aire